# Formula works on page layout, but displays #Error! on Report

Tags: reporting, formula, formula-field, datetime, date

I have an issue. I have a text field to store survey completion date and time. I created a formula field to capture date only.

DATEVALUE( completion_time__c)

It is showing correct date on Page layout but when I drag this field into report. It is showing Error.

Please help me to figure out the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please specify what error you get

Comment: Did you check every record about the Completion_time__c? I mean to say, Is the Format that you have given in completion_time__c is correct in all the records?

Comment: Do all the records that appear in the report have the correct date on the page layout? I'm thinking maybe 1 wrong-formatted record breaks the whole report column.. What if you filter the report to only show records of which you're sure they are correct?

Comment: I have checked and all have a valid completion date time. Survey created date is also capture correct date.

Comment: Can you post your formula too, i think the error lies there!

Comment: DATEVALUE( completion_time__c)

Answer (score 2):

I used this formula and it worked.

```
DATE(
VALUE(LEFT(Completion_Time__c,4)), 
VALUE(MID(Completion_Time__c,6,2)), 
VALUE(MID(Completion_Time__c,9,2))
)
```

Comment: This is the answer. I used this formula and it's working fine.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your Completion Date is DateTime, then you have to use `DateValue(CustomFieldDate__c)` in your formula field.

If it is text field, use VALUE().

This error occurs because of the dataType mismatch only.

Comment: No, The problem is Completion Date is Text data type. @sfdcFanBoy

Comment: Oh I didnt know it is text field. Yes if it is text field, need to use VALUE()

Answer (score 0):

According salesforce developer forum (which is chosen best answer from admin and solved question), that guy has the same issue with yours.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xCaIAI

> My guess is that it is showing error because your converting date to text, again creating DateValue from text, report is not able to compile it. Just guessing...